# How to send acknowledgement response back to slack modal on view_submission action

Tags: slack, slack-api

I have a modal and on the submit of the modal I do some other third party action. The actions run properly but it gives me a generic error saying something went wrong.

I found this in the slack documentation:

> If your app responds to a `view_submission` event with a basic acknowledgment response — an HTTP 200 response — this will immediately close the submitted view, and remove it from the view stack. (Note: your HTTP 200 response must be empty for this step to complete successfully.)

> If there are no more views left in the stack, the modal will close. Otherwise, the modal will display the next view down in the stack.

> [Link to Doc](https://api.slack.com/surfaces/modals/using#close_current_view)

I understand that I have to respond with a 200 response, but where do I respond to?
I don't get any `response_urls` in my `view_submission` action.